# How to update default error text in media browser for Android Auto?

Tags: android, android-auto

I am working on the Android auto media app and I want to set custom error text (or custom background text) when loading items has failed due to a network error etc. By default there are only two edge case scenarios:

1. "No items" text will be displayed when MediaBrowserServiceCompat's `onLoadChildren()` method returns an empty list.
2. Generic "Something went wrong" text with an exclamation mark icon is when an error occurred.

Is there any way I can update one or another? 
So far I found only one media app that displays a custom message for the second scenario in Android auto. That's Spotify with a message "Spotify is currently set to offline", though the default error icon is the same.
I couldn't find any mentioning of the error messages in `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` documentation and will appreciate any help.

What I've tried so far setting the error state for the media session and returning a null as a result:

```
@Override
    public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull final String parentId, @NonNull final Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {
        // some logic ...

        PlaybackStateCompat errorState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP)
                .setErrorMessage(PlaybackStateCompat.ERROR_CODE_UNKNOWN_ERROR, "MY CUSTOM ERROR TEXT!").build();
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(errorState);
        // result.sendError(new Bundle()); // <- does nothing
        // result.sendResult(Collections.emptyList()); // default "No items" message will be displayed
        result.sendResult(null);  // <-- this should trigger an error
}
```

`MediaBrowserServiceCompat.Result` has a method `sendError` but it should only be called on custom action (according to the documentation) and there are no examples of how to use it:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/MediaBrowserServiceCompat.Result.html#sendError(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Before you check for these issues, make sure you should have an Android phone running Android 5.0 (Lollipop). For best performance, I recommend Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) and up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer, the MediaSessionCompat's playback state should be updated to the STATE_ERROR. Here is a sample code for showing an error:

```
void setErrorState(String errorMessage) {
        PlaybackStateCompat playbackState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_ERROR, 0, 0f)
                .setErrorMessage(
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ERROR_CODE_AUTHENTICATION_EXPIRED,
                        errorMessage
                )
                .build();
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackState);
    }
```